# YASM mov instruction gives error: invalid size for operand 1

Tags: assembly, tasm, yasm

I am trying to do some basic YASM coming from TASM, and this line of code will error:

```
mov [var], 7
```

I have defined the variable like so: `var db 5`.
Even after trying to do `var: db 5` it still errored out and said:

> error: invalid size for operand 1

Answer (score 5):

Unlike TASM, YASM/NASM don't look at the declaration of `var` to decide if it is byte, word, dword, etc.  The operand size needs to be specified in any instruction where it isn't implicit from the registers being used.  So you must write

```
mov byte [var], 7
```

Note that

```
mov [var], bl
```

doesn't need the `byte`, because the 8-bit operand size is inferred from the use of the 8-bit register `bl`.

Comment: @sefsf: It applies to `[var]`.  Though actually `mov [var], byte 7` also works - both operands to `mov` must have the same size, so it's enough if it knows the size of one of them.

Comment: They are other possible methods how to specify the operand size:  
GAS uses mnemonic suffix `b`,`w`,`l`  
€ASM looks at the type of `var`, too, otherwise it uses either suffix or instruction modifier, e.g. `data=byte`, see https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#DATAeq

Comment: @nate-eldredge is this just for MOV or any instruction that calls for the variable?

Comment: @sefsf: It applies to any instruction with a memory operand.  You need it in particular for instructions whose other operand is an immediate (`add byte [var], 7` or `add [var], byte 7`), one-operand instructions (`neg byte [var]`), and instructions with two operands of different sizes (`movsx eax, byte [var]`).

Comment: @nate-eldredge Thanks!